# Is it possible to transpose a column of text values into a single row without duplicates based on an if statement?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, unique, google-sheets-formula, transpose

E.g. I have the following sheet and formula, but I only want to transpose the data if it contains a specific month, specified in A2.

[image: Screenshot of spreadsheet]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(A5:A; B5:B=A2)))
```

Comment: much simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query for that.

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A5:C, "select A where month(B)+2="&MONTH(A2)&""))
```

The reason we add +1 is because months in a query start from 0

[image]